# Id is not resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

I am developing my `first program` using `Android`. It adds or subtracts to a total depending on which button the user clicks. I have made its `xml` and now I was creating its `java` but I getting some errors(Its not fully developed yet). I would be helpful if anyone can guide me.

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Total is 0" 
        android:gravity="center"    

        />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:text="Button" />  


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:text="Button" />



</LinearLayout>
```

### Java Source File

```
package com.fahad.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidProject1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int numberCount;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        numberCount =0;
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bAdd);<!--error-->
        sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSub);<!--error-->
        display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);<!--error-->

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }
}
```

### Error

```
Id is not resolved or is not a field
```

Please help me out with this error. Thanks.

### EDIT

Pasting its .R file,

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package com.fahad.project;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040001;
        public static final int hello=0x7f040000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ID values from your XML layout.  Try...

```
add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

You may want to give them more descriptive IDs moving forward!

You haven't given the `TextView` an ID in your XML, I will leave that one for you to fix :]

Answer (score 1):

Ok! which id do you put in xml layout is generated automatically in `R.id` class.

for example:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />
```

in this xml Button tag you put  `android:id="@+id/button1"`  and id as `button1` is automatically added to `R.id`

And you connect your Button in java code using this id not your own

like this

```
add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Try From Eclipse Menu> Project>clean.

Comment: I went and see my .R file, it does not have it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared buttons ids as "button1" and "button2" but refer to them as "bAdd" and "bSub" which won't work.

If your code doesn't compile even when you corrected the references, do the Right Click on the project -> Refresh and Project->Clean in Eclipse.

If it still doesn't work then you have probably messed up the project setup. Since you are obviously doing some first steps only, just create a new project and copy your code there.